# Oracle Bulk Load takes the schema of the current connection

Tags: c#, oracle, bulk-load

Oracle Bulk Load takes the schema of the current connection, is there a way to prevent it from doing so? Just in case I can't create such a synonym, I just post. That is to say that when loading the bulk load it does not take any scheme.

```
public class BulkLoader
    {
        public static void LoadBulkData(string connectionString, DataTable data, string tableName)
        {
            ConnectionProvider provider = new ConnectionProvider(connectionString);
            using (OracleConnection connection = provider.GetConnection())
            {
                OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                        foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                        {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                        }

                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw new Exception("Se produjo un error durante la carga masiva.", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The indicated table is the correct one but it always takes the schema of the current connection something like Schema.Table and should be just Table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DestinationSchemaName to nominate the target schema.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/OracleBulkCopyMembers.html#GUID-80BDCCC2-09DA-4F47-8A9B-28969B078749